# OpenCV Python Split -> Laplacian -> HoughCircles = Assertion failed.

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to perform a hough circles operation on an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhWSO.png) after I have split the channels, blurred the results from the split (individually), and applied a Laplacian operation to the constituent components.

```
img = cv2.imread(fileName)


b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
kSize = 3
gBlur = cv2.blur(g, (kSize, kSize))
print(gBlur.shape)
test = np.array([])
gEdges = cv2.Laplacian(gBlur, cv2.CV_64F)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gEdges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 40, 10,
                        param1=50,param2=60,minRadius=2,maxRadius=15)
```

However, I am getting an Error from OpenCV stating:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (!_image.empty() && 
_image.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) && 
(_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat())) in HoughCircles, file 
/io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp, line 1659
```

and

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp:1659: 
error: (-215) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) 
+ (((1)-1) << 3)) && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function 
HoughCircles
```

I don't understand why this is occurring. The image is in grayscale. I've also tried changing the data type in the Laplacian operation to cv2.CV_16U, cv2.CV_8U even; however those result in a blank image - and opencv throws a different error as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image type you have mentioned in the `cv2.Laplacian` is the problem. The other thing is your code was not completed. So here is the completed code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('stack1.png')    

b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
kSize = 3
gBlur = cv2.blur(g, (kSize, kSize))
print(gBlur.shape)
test = np.array([])
gEdges = cv2.Laplacian(gBlur, cv2.CV_8UC1)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gEdges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 40, 10, param1=50,param2=60,minRadius=2,maxRadius=15)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```